# Issue with ExpressionEngine caching file permissions

Tags: permissions, caching

I am trying to allow caching for my site using expressionengine 2.0. In my config.php file, I have set the following two parameters:

```
$config['cache_driver'] = 'file';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
```

Initially there was no cache directory, so I created a cache directory with 755 permissions. However, on expressengine's admin page, when I try to set caching to File, it keeps on saying in a writing next to it in red:

[image]

Note that my cache directory doesn't have anything in it. Its at the correct path

www/mysite/system/expressionengine/cache

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Some sever setups require 777 permissions on writable directories. Have you tried that?

Comment: That works, but ideally that shouldn't be the solution.

Comment: It all depends on how your server is setup, not really anything EE can do about this - my guess is you're running PHP as a CGI module and the user that process runs under doesn't have the proper file system permissions.

Comment: Makes sense. Ill look into that-Thank you!